# How can I use separate power source for the Arduino and the motors

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, battery, raspberrypi, l298n

[image]How can use a separate power source for powering Arduino, and another battery for powering the motors?
How can I make connections through the motor driver module L298N? I know how normally we use one battery to power the Arduino as well as the motors. But I am facing the problem while using different power sources.

Comment: make sure all ground pins are connected together. And please edit your answer and insert a photo of your setup so others can spot your problem

Comment: I added the Image and want to know how the pins are connected when separate power source are used

Comment: please edit the image so it's clearly visible which cable goes to which terminal, especially on the arduino and the L298 module

Comment: That's what I want to know

Comment: seems correctly connected ... two control signals and ground connected between the arduino and the motor driver

Comment: Read the documentation of the motor driver module. If it doesn't seem to answer your question, update the question with a link to that documentation.

Comment: You already are powering the motor with a separate power source - the 9V battery (poor choice, btw). The Arduino is powered by the 5V from the Pi.

Comment: @Majenko Ya I know it's already connected but I want to know the actual connections of the pins, The connections made in the diagram are not properly visible

Comment: @AmitNikhade your post only asks about separate power supplies ... if you want to ask about control lines, then you should open a new post ... document exactly what module you have and how it is connected (pin numbers, signal names) ... give details about what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

That motor driver has an optional on-board 5V regulator. It can be enabled / disabled with a jumper.

With that regulator enabled you just need to connect a ground and your control signals (ENA/IN1/IN2 or ENB/IN3/IN4).

If you disable that regulator (remove the jumper) then you need to provide power from the Arduino's 5V pin to the +5V screw terminal.

The ENx pin(s) (after removing any jumpers that may be on them) connect to any PWM capable pin (this is the speed control pin). IN1/IN2 or IN3/IN4 connect to any IO pin since these are just used to set the direction or control the braking modes.  ENA controls the speed of motor 1, and IN1/IN2 control the direction of motor 1. ENB and IN3/IN4 are likewise for motor 2.

Comment: You mean to say that do not remove the jumper of the 5v regulator and then connect the ENA/IN1/IN2  And It's ready.

Comment: PLus ground, but yes. That's right.

Comment: And the battery connections

Comment: Well, yes, of course. Without those there will be no power...

Comment: So I will be able to power the arduino with a separate battery or through USB. And what about the motor driver connections with the other battery for motors.

Comment: What about them? You connect them. You connect the battery to the connections for the battery.

Comment: It worked, Thank's

Comment: I completed the circuit as you said but my raspberry pi suddenly start booting and Now only showing a red light

Comment: Maybe your Pi's power supply is not good enough to power the Arduino as well as the Pi. They can be very picky.

Comment: It's working now. My god everything working well now